# Use cases for recursive function in Javascript front-end web development

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to learn more about JavaScript recursive function, but I couldn't find examples of using it for front-end web development. (I only find factorial example, which is not very useful for me).

What are the common cases I should use recursive function for front-end web development?

Comment: Check out [jQuery source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js). You'll find plenty of examples.

Comment: This is a great resource for [javascript design patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The #1 use-case of recursion in client-side javascript is tree traversing. Since both DOM and JSON are tree structures, most of the time you use recursion to traverse them, following the "do something with a node and repeat the same with its descendant nodes" pattern, like for example:

```
 uppercase_text_nodes(node):  // pseudocode
       if node.type == TEXT
           node.value = node.text.toUpperCase
       else for each child in node.children
           uppercase_text_nodes(child)
```

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: javathon also known as pythonscript ;)

Comment: Oh, there's a reason it made me think of python.

Answer (score 1):

An example could be:

```
var walkDOM = function (node) {
  var func = function (node) {
    console.log(node);
  };

  func(node);
  node = node.firstElementChild;

  while (node) {
    walkDOM(node);
    node = node.nextSibling;
  }
};

const parentEl = document.getElementById('parent');
walkDOM(parentEl);
```